# style.behavior is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<ol class="myclass cls">
<li class="mylicls">
</li>
</ol>
```

in my css there are myclass, cls, mylicls defined already

I would want to output the above div into

```
<ol class="myclass cls" style="behavior:url(/path/something.htc)">
<li class="mylicls">
</li>
</ol>
```

here is my javascript

```
document.getElementsByTagName(ol).style.behavior="url(/path/something.htc)";
```

in Firefox: style.behavior is not defined
in IE: Object is null or undefined

Comment: So, let's take a guess as to *what* might be returning `undefined` .. (I would guess `getElementsByTagName(ol)` is wrong, and I am surprised it is not generating a ReferenceError.)

Comment: Likely. In any case this error indicates the *call* to `getElements..` is returning null/defined.

Comment: I edit to clarify that matter

Comment: Check the answer of Alex at bottom,that may help.

Comment: In `getElementsByTagName(ol)` `ol` is an `undefined` variable. Perhaps it should be quoted?

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementsByTagName(ol)` is returning null.

You probably meant `document.getElementsByTagName("ol")`.

But even then you have a list of nodes, not single nodes, and you would have to apply the style to each one.

```
var ols = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");
for (var i = 0; i < ols.length; i++) {
  var el = ols[i];
  el.style.behavior = "url(/path/something.htc)";
};
```

And *even then* `behaviour` in non-standard, and only works in IE, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you, I actually would like to make a `border-radius.htc` to work with prev versions of IEs but although the above code works the radius doesn't get any changes at all

Comment: I don't know a damn thing about IE behaviors, except the fact they only work in IE. So I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` does not return a single element but a list of elements - but only if it finds something. So you need to add `[0]` **and** make sure that you actually find at least one element. Since you want `<ol>` tags pass a string `'ol'` to the function (you forgot the quotes).

Besides that, `behavior` only exists in IE. So using it in any other browser will fail anyway. Obviously this means you shouldn't use it at all unless you need to shim some functionality IE lacks but other browsers already have.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - as it implies it is failing because it is running in FF - in context.

Comment: Ah I see. I blame the shitty wording of the asker for it. If people just bothered to understand how markdown worked in regard to linebreaks....